# Does PyCharm have any tool for time-tracking?

Tags: python, pycharm

I just checked out http://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/ for Eclipse to do time tracking and stuff automatically. Does PyCharm have something similar?

Answer (score 5):

This is an automatic time tracker for PyCharm:

https://wakatime.com/pycharm (official site)

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7425?pr=pycharm (plugin page)

Comment: whats this "insert your api key" thing?

Comment: @johnktejik that's how it sends your coding activity to the WakaTime API so it shows up on your personal dashboard at https://wakatime.com

Answer (score 3):

For now you can install Time Tracker plug-in with PyCharm support from here: https://github.com/a-iv/IntelliJ-Time-Tracker/releases/download/0.5/TimeTracker_0.5.zip

Sources available here: https://github.com/a-iv/IntelliJ-Time-Tracker/

I hope author will publish update soon and it will be available on plugins.intellij.net

Comment: Doesn't work for me: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on PyCharm 3.1

Comment: @AlexChe seems like an issue in Darcula and IntelliJ themes.

Comment: I've fixed an issue in Darcula and IntelliJ themes in version 0.5.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to Preferences>Plugins you can search for Time Trackers plugins.

[image]
As you can see, I've installed the [Darkyen's Time Tracker](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9286-darkyen-s-time-tracker).

The red arrow points to where this plugin shows you the timer.

Answer (score 2):

There are some IntelliJ IDEA plugins for time tracking, but as far as I can see none of them have been updated for PyCharm compatibility.

You can try to contact the author of Time Tracker plugin and ask him to update it for PyCharm compatibility:
http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=3806

Comment: You can find Time Tracker compatible with the current PyCharm version here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239838/523461.